# How to define MIME types with Create-React-App's node server?

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, webassembly

I'm trying to deal with this WebAssembly note: "Note: To run with `instantiateStreaming` and `compileStreaming`, you need your webserver to serve .wasm file with `application/wasm` MIME type. The https crate can be used to serve files from localhost, and includes the application/wasm MIME type out of the box."

Indeed, I get a MIME error in the JS console. A Google search revealed no way to configure this. Mozilla recommends instantiateStreaming over the depricated WebAssembly.instantiate. The latter doesn't work for me either, if using stdweb or bindgen: It wants a second argument which I'm not sure how to provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you're working on the bleeding edge here! WebAssembly streaming compilation is a very new feature that is only [currently supported in FireFox and Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiateStreaming).

You are right that it depends on files being server with the correct mime-type. The changes required to make this happen being made:

- node-mime - which is used by many projects (including webpack dev server) to provide mime type based on file extension, was [updated to support wasm in Dec 2017](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime/commit/3f775bafa8bff0c1a4bd94bb07ab3065676e44f6) in v2.3.1
- webpack-dev-middleware was [updated in Nov 2017](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/commit/91506f352ffb4fb1e2ac75d1f1425d0906830266) to support wasm file extension in v3.1.3

However, these are both up-stream dependencies of create-react-app, via react-scripts. The bleeding edge version of react-scripts [has a dependency on webback-dev-middleware that supports wasm](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/package.json), however this hasn't been released yet. The latest version on npm uses an older version.

For now, I'd turn of streaming compilation until these changes make it into 'production'.

Comment: Now four years later and this is still an issue. Surely there's a way to get the correct mime type by now?