# How can I import Emscripten generated .wasm/js files in files created with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, emscripten, webassembly

I have a library I can successfully build & run with the `Emscripten` generated .html files.  I'd like to use it with React now, however, I get a MIME type error` which I can't fix.  Here are the steps I take to generate the React app and .wasm files

```
npx create-react-app stackoverflow

DEST=stackoverflow/src/stackoverflow.html

sudo docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src trzeci/emscripten emmake make

$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src trzeci/emscripten emcc \
    ... o. files
    -s MODULARIZE=1 \
    -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 \
    -s EXPORT_NAME=Stackoverflow \
    -o ${DEST}

# disable eslint for the generate file
sed -i '1s;^;/* eslint-disable */\n;' ${DEST}
```

I expect to be able to import the `Stackoverflow` object inside of `stackoverflow.js`

```
App.js
...

import Stackoverflow from './stackoverflow';
console.log(Stackoverflow());

...
```

However the dev server fails to load, and the console shows these warnings.

```
m streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.
(anonymous) @ stackoverflow.js:1667
Promise.then (async)
createWasm @ stackoverflow.js:1663
Module.asm @ stackoverflow.js:1694
(anonymous) @ stackoverflow.js:5322
./src/App.js @ App.js:5
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:781
fn @ bootstrap:149
./src/index.js @ index.css?f3f6:45
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:781
fn @ bootstrap:149
0 @ stackoverflow.js:5867
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:781
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
stackoverflow.js:1668 falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
(anonymous) @ stackoverflow.js:1668
Promise.then (async)
createWasm @ stackoverflow.js:1663
Module.asm @ stackoverflow.js:1694
(anonymous) @ stackoverflow.js:5322
./src/App.js @ App.js:5
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:781
fn @ bootstrap:149
./src/index.js @ index.css?f3f6:45
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:781
fn @ bootstrap:149
0 @ stackoverflow.js:5867
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:781
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
stackoverflow.js:1654 failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
```

The first error reported says that the MIME type is wrong, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518028/how-to-define-mime-types-with-create-react-apps-node-server) question tells me to update `node-mime` and `webpack-dev-server`.  `node-mime` isn't present in my `node_modules`, but `webpack-dev-server` is and [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1575) issue, which has apparently solved my problem is available on 3.3.1.

`$ npm run eject`

And then I change my `webpack-dev-server` version to 3.3.1 and install.

Now I run `npm run start` and step through the code, I can confirm I get to the correct dev-server.

Yet my error persists.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Are you using Webpack or any bundler?

Comment: Yes, `create-react-app` uses it under the hood and if you `eject` the config you can see the webpack & webpack-dev-server scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do a couple of things to get this to work, Most of my troubleshooting here was futile (the dev server was not serving the .wasm files at all, it falls back on the .html when it can't find what you want, this was the source of my MIME errors).

**HOW TO MAKE EMSCRIPTEN JAVASCRIPT WORK WITH create-react-app**

1. Copy the .wasm output of the `emcc` to the `react-app/public` folder `cp stackoverflow.wasm gifsicle-react/public/stackoverflow.wasm`
2. Add `eslint-disable` to the top of your files (I use this sed command) `sed -i.old '1s;^;\/* eslint-disable *\/;' stackoverflow.js`
3. Replace the relative path of the `.wasm` file in the .js with an absolute one.  (This is necessary to get files in the `/public` directory) `sed -i.old "s|stackoverflow.wasm|/stackoverflow.wasm|" stackoverflow.js`
4. The generated javascript will try to resolve the path relative to the website directory.  Comment out this line
   `sed -i.old "s|wasmBinaryFile = locateFile|// wasmBinaryFile = locateFile|" stackoverflow.js`

I ended up writing [this](https://medium.com/@marvin_78330/webassembly-react-and-create-react-app-8b73346c9b65) blog post which has more detail about how I managed this.